# python infix operator on a list of objects

Tags: python, matrix, infix-notation, infix-operator

I'm using a library for mathematical optimization (PICOS) in a jupyter notebook.

In PICOS, the symbols `//` and `&` are infix operators for vertical and horizontal concatenation, to build matrices out of blocks. Note that I cannot use `numpy.bmat` because the blocks are not numpy objects.

If I have a list of blocks, say `[A,B,C]`, I would form a matrix by concatenating them horizontally with the notation `A & B & C`, for instance. The problem arises when the list contains hundreds of symbols and I cannot build the matrix by hand. Is there a simple way of interposing an infix between each symbol in a list?

Comment: Iterate through the blocks, adding to a counter block each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have been less hasty. I just did it with a recursive function:

```
def concat_horizontal(lst):
if len(lst) == 2:
    return lst[0] & lst[1]
else:
    return concat_horizontal([lst[0] & lst[1]] + lst[2:])
```

and an analogous one for the vertical concatenation. Yay, recursion!

Comment: I'm not a programmer, my instinct is all off. Besides, recursion is beautiful!

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `reduce` metafunction ([Python 2.7 docu](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reduce), [Python 3 docu](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce)) with the [`operators.and_(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#operator.and_) representing the `&` infix operator as a function of two arguments:

```
from functools import reduce
from operators import and_

def concat_horizontal(iterable_of_affine_expressions):
    return reduce(and_, iterable_of_affine_expressions)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'&'.join([A,B,C])
```

or

```
' & '.join([A,B,C])
```

if you want spaces between the `&`

EDIT:

also wrap it inside `eval`

```
eval(' & '.join([A,B,C]))
```

Comment: Oops. Didn't realize it shouldn't be a string. You could wrap it in `eval` I suppose.

Comment: Using `eval` is generally not good advice. It probably wouldn't hurt in this instance, but it certainly wouldn't be performant. The proper solution is to iterate!

Comment: `join` complains that it was expecting a string